# Why is Pelican static site generator adding hash and slug in URL

Tags: python, pelican

I have a pelican blog which works fine except for one weird problem. I have the same files source-controlled locally and on the server. I build the site on the server with `make publish` to publish.

But on the server, I get one *tiny* difference: the URL looks like `siteurl/slug/#slug` (with the extra # and slug again) instead of `siteurl/slug/`

I have the same pelican version (3.6.3) as my local machine, same configuration files, and theme.

(only difference is python version: locally 2.7.9, on the server: 2.7.6 but I doubt this is the cause.)

My pelicanconf.py:

```
ARTICLE_URL = '{slug}/'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}/index.html'
PAGE_URL = '{slug}/'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}/index.html'
CATEGORY_URL = 'category/{slug}/'
CATEGORY_SAVE_AS = 'category/{slug}/index.html'
```

My publishconf.py:

```
SITEURL = '//mysite.com'
RELATIVE_URLS = False

FEED_ALL_ATOM = 'feeds/all.atom.xml'
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = 'feeds/%s.atom.xml'

DELETE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been using the theme Flex and the #slug is added by the theme. (file: templates/index.html)

I had forgotten that I had already removed this in the past in my local machine, but not in the server itself.